# Continuity and complex derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

> Investigate the continuity and complex differentiability of the following functions $f$. Find the derivatives at points where they exist.
>
> - $f(z)=z \ \text{Re}(z)$.

To show that this functions is differentiable is very easy. But how can I find the derivative? I tried to use the definition of complex differentiability, but that didn't work.

> This question also for the functions:
>
> - $f(z)=\bar z$; and
> - $f(z)=z \cdot \bar z$
>
> (where $\bar z$ is the notation for the conjugate of $z$).

Comment: Any function of a complex variable that uses $\operatorname{Im}(z)$, $\operatorname{Re}(z)$, ${\overline z}$, or $|z|$ in an essential way is almost certainly not differentiable (in the complex sense).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If we write $z = x + iy$ with $x, y$ real numbers, then the function is

$$f(z) = (x + iy)(x) = x^2 + i xy$$

Let $u = x^2$ and $v = xy$ be the real and imaginary parts of $f$, respectively. Then by the Cauchy-Riemann equations,

$$u_x = v_y$$ and $$u_y = - v_x$$

The first equation leads to $2x = x$, and the second leads to $0 = -y$, so....

Comment: I think you meant 2x=x and 0=-y? So y=0 and x=0. Thus, it's only differentiable in (0,0), thus f(z)=0 -> complexe derivative is 0?

Comment: @RoosJansen Yes, I did mean $2x = x$. This implies that the function is only differentiable at $0$. The derivative is then given by $u_x + i v_x = 2x + i y = 0 + 0i = 0$.

Comment: Is the derivative always given by u_x+i*v_x? Or can you also use u_y+iv_y?